# определить как часто в массиве данных присутствует заданный бит

Tags: c++, оптимизация, битовые-операции

Подскажите, есть ли какое-то безусловное (без использования условий) решение следующей задаче:

Есть массив 32битных чисел. Требуется на выходе получить 32битное число, где если i-ый бит установлен, то это означает, что i-ый бит в массиве данных встречается 2 раза, в противном случае i-ый бит сброшен

Т.е. к примеру

```
0b1011
0b1001
0b0010
0b1100
------
0b0011
```

понятно, что задачу можно решить создав массив из 32 элементов и когда бит в элементе массива установлен - увеличивать значение соответствующей ячейки массива

```
arr[32] = {0};
for (const int value : data)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 32; index ++)
    {
        if (value & (1 << index))
            arr[index] ++;
    }
}

int res = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < 32; index ++)
    res |= arr[index] == 2 ? (1 << index) : 0;
```

но есть ли способ обойтись без этого `if` и вообще цикла по битам

частично конечно можно сделать так:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < 32; index ++)
        arr[index] += (value & (1 << index)) >> index;
```

но это полумера

Comment: Думаю, что иного способа, кроме как посчитать все биты нет. Не исключено, что я плохо думал. Вся сложность в том, что нужно найти ровно две единицы среди множества.

Comment: Жаль, что ровно 2, а не просто четное число раз :)

Comment: Жека Диулин, вот и я не могу пока найти - если бы надо было найти четное кол-во - то это можно делать через `xor`, с другой стороны во вторую переменную если пихать `or` - это будет означать больше 0, вот таким подходом возможно что-то можно сделать, но я пока не нашел

Comment: @Harry, именно так :)))

Comment: а какой контекст этой задачи?

Comment: вместо цикла по битам можете создать массив масок - думаю будет нагляднее и даже быстрее

Comment: @user7860670, ну если совсем просто - это компактная запись точек на 32 прямых и мне нужны прямые на которых находится ровно 2 точки и надо знать какие именно точки

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, если вы про то чтобы развернуть цикл, то мне кажется, компиляторы сейчас настолько умные, что сами это сделают (можно для интереса посмотреть в диазссемблере), т.е. цикл они развернут, но вот основной алгоритм изменить не смогут и if все равно будет присутствовать или ужмется в тот вариант, который я показал

Comment: тогда их надо хранить наоборот - 32 массива бит, тогда можно линейно пробежаться и считать количество точек

Comment: @user7860670, тогда другие алгоримы работы будут очень сложными (много лишних операций) :) но данная задача вызывается гораздо реже, но все равно свое время отъедает и довольно заметное

Comment: ну тогда храните сразу оба варианта

Comment: @Zhihar при использовании масок можно обойтись без if - просто результат операции & добавляете в счетчик. Таким образом количество элементов в вашем счетчике будет `counter / mask = n`

Comment: Можно попробовать развернуть `for (int index = 0; index < 32; index ++) arr[index] += (value & (1 << index)) >> index;` в 32 строки с константными сдвигами и померять, будет ли разница

Comment: можно, но надо подумать.

Comment: пришел один вариант в голову - добавил как ответ к своему вопросу

Answer (score 6):

пришла в голову следующая логика:

как получить 2

1. установить бит в переменной 1 (т.е. бит встречался хотя бы 1 раз)
2. установить бит в переменной 2, если бит в переменной 1 уже был установлен (т.е. бит встречался хотя бы 2 раза)
3. установить бит в переменной 3, если бит в переменной 2 уже был установлен (т.е. бит встречался хотя бы 3 раза)

правда порядок 3 - 2 - 1 должен быть

в итоге в конце в переменных 1 и 2 биты должны быть установлены, а в переменной 3 - нет - это и будет показатель того, что было всего 2 бита в данных

```
int bits1 = 0;
int bits2 = 0;
int bits3 = 0;

for (const int value : data)
{
    bits3 |= bits2 & value;
    bits2 |= bits1 & value;
    bits1 |= value;
}

const int res = bits1 & bits2 & (~bits3);
```

что скажете?

Comment: Отличный алгоритм! Кстати финальный результат можно упростить `res = bits2 & ~bits3;`.

Comment: @Arty, можно пойти на замену bits2 на res и тогда в конце `res &= ~bits3;`

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned int a = 0, b = 0;
unsigned int x[5] = { 1, 3, 5, 4, 8 }; // Ну, сколько надо :)

// Магический цикл :)
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    unsigned int s = a;
    a = a|(b&x[i]);
    b = (b&~x[i])|(~s&x[i]);
}
// Получение нужного результата
unsigned int z = a&b;
```

Ну, как вариант -

```
unsigned int step(unsigned int x, unsigned int &a, unsigned int&b)
{
    unsigned int s = a;
    a = a|(b&x);
    b = (b&~x)|(~s&x);
    return a&b;
}
```

Изначально `a` и `b` должны быть нулями; они хранят текущее состояние. Меньше, чем два бита на состояние, обойтись не получится. После каждого нового `x` функция возвращает искомое число. Его же можно в любой момент получить как `a&b`.

Логику конечного автомата пояснять надо или она очевидна?

Comment: `unsigned int` приходится использовать потому что в `int`  один из битов отвечает за `+`/`-`?

Comment: @Danis Потому как битовые операции гарантированно работают с unsigned, насколько я помню, а вот с signed - там какие-то неприятности теоретически возможны, кажется...

Answer (score 1):

Придумал быстрый алгоритм.

Для N чисел будет `3 * N` итераций, всего `9 * N` битовых операций не считая итерирования переменной цикла. Причём ровно столько же операций будет и для 64-битных чисел (на 64-битном процессоре) вместо 32-битных чисел, если надо расширить задачу до 64-битных чисел (поменять строку `using WordT ...`).

После прохода первых k чисел cnt[i] хранит u32 такой что j-й бит у него равен 1 тогда и только тогда когда в этих первых k числах j-й бит встретился ровно i раз. j-й бит всегда установлен ровно в одном из cnt[i] (0 <= i < 4).

Если в очередном числе j-й бит равен 1 и при этом также в неком cnt[i] также j-й бит равен 1, то этот единичный бит переходит в j-й бит в cnt[i + 1], а j-й бит cnt[i] зануляется, такой операцией мы увеличиваем на 1 подсчитанное число единиц в j-й позиции.

Массив cnt всегда содержит ровно 4 элемента для нашей задачи, не зависимо от N. В начале cnt[0] содержит все единичные биты, а остальные cnt[i] (1 <= i < 4) равны нулю.

В конце ответом будет cnt[2].

Для дальнейшего ускорения (оптимизации) можно внутренний цикл развернуть (unroll), хотя современные компиляторы итак это часто делают, там всего ровно 3 итерации у него всегда. Можно даже `cnt` массив заменить на несколько переменных типа uint32_t.

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##bZLdTsIwFMfv@xQnmpihfGzIhWFjT2HihUEytkGaQEe2zkQRIyTGC6PPgijGBOEZ2ieaZx0fQ222ne5/2v/5nabuYFByew7rJskhZW4v9nywrn2XB6FNdoobcY8ynpdoEPHQd/p5rU155O@tcsLQubEJiSPKunARhN45NCBGr9Nqi5uE4Az6DmVaAYYEcFQqwCKQY7ESH2IuH8Sn@JITEDP5qKSlfBZzkE@ojsVCTIsgFvJVvGEyJ69AvmCYi298l3KC2VlZ@WMn9XrWoaV47LReA4Z629ANowhp1FXEoKt/FEbmhs5FYqQZo/E78kz/suIEy4klUtR@c0xzFOpwMogi1GzljCD3StH0AtbOnnXxThCC5sQ8AFZH6M2JbVMDHnq002lxoOiDbuWI3vp4siUwTNTsBugmlEo0vzMdyrOf7bmkTTgCZu4tWOtXDej/k4ATMJpwt5cckd1XNesGMQfLggO9fZBGJWYXxkoxg46m@i7AMZzZWmpcbRa2K33m9UwyIknyAw)

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <array>

using WordT = uint32_t;

int main() {
    // ns содержит входные числа, любое число элементов.
    std::vector<WordT> ns = {0b1011, 0b1001, 0b0010, 0b1100};
    // cnt всегда содержит ровно 4 элемента.
    std::array<WordT, 4> cnt = {~WordT(0), 0, 0, 0};
    for (auto n: ns) {
        for (ptrdiff_t i = cnt.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            auto m = cnt[i] & n;
            cnt[i] ^= m;
            cnt[i + 1] |= m;
        }
    }
    // ответ всегда будет в cnt[2]
    std::cout << "0b" << std::bitset<sizeof(WordT) * 8>(cnt[2]) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
0b00000000000000000000000000000011
```

Также можно заметить что на самом деле операция `cnt[i] ^= m;` лишняя и не нужна, если финальный ответ взять как `cnt[2] & ~cnt[3]`, в итоге получаем сокращённый (и ускоренный) алгоритм из `6 * N` битовых операций:

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##ZZHfTsIwFMbv9xQnmJhNGWzAhWF/nsLEC0PI2AZpAh3ZOhNFiJAYL4w@C6IYE4RnaJ9onnUKU5st5/Q77Xd@bf3xWPeHHh1k2RGh/jANQrCvQp9FsascFD9hAaGsLJEoYXHojcpaj7Ak/LXKi2Pv2lWUNCF0ABdRHJyDAyl6NRtdZikKZjDyCFU1mCiAo14HmoCY8x1/42txx9/5h1gAX4l7KW3FI1@DeEB1zjd8WQW@Ec/8BYsleQfiCcOaf@K/FQusrmrSH0/SbhcntCWPm/dzYGL0TMM0q5BHQ0YMhpyjMLV@6HwkRpo5Gr8iz/I/KybYjm@RovWXY1mikJdTQFSh5UpnBJlJRTU07F183837UQyql7IIaBuhNSnuC2MWB6Tf7zIg6IJetYTchHivOpgWaq4DhgW6Tg778oELLwmcgtmBW6eYdeAYqHXg9KOUgW1DxehV8ijF4q3tvEfUVyWyBidw5qq5RyP3mOVZs6Pt94Q0GFrKNMu@AA)

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <array>

using WordT = uint32_t;

int main() {
    // ns содержит входные числа, любое число элементов.
    std::vector<WordT> ns = {0b1011, 0b1001, 0b0010, 0b1100};
    // cnt всегда содержит ровно 4 элемента.
    std::array<WordT, 4> cnt = {~WordT(0), 0, 0, 0};
    for (auto n: ns)
        for (ptrdiff_t i = cnt.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            cnt[i + 1] |= cnt[i] & n;
    std::cout << "0b" << std::bitset<sizeof(WordT) * 8>(cnt[2] & ~cnt[3]) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Совсем без if-ов не получилось (используется тернарный оператор при получении итогового значения)

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

const std::array<unsigned int, 32> masks = {
    0b00000000000000000000000000000001, 0b00000000000000000000000000000010,
    0b00000000000000000000000000000100, 0b00000000000000000000000000001000,
    0b00000000000000000000000000010000, 0b00000000000000000000000000100000,
    0b00000000000000000000000001000000, 0b00000000000000000000000010000000,
    0b00000000000000000000000100000000, 0b00000000000000000000001000000000,
    0b00000000000000000000010000000000, 0b00000000000000000000100000000000,
    0b00000000000000000001000000000000, 0b00000000000000000010000000000000,
    0b00000000000000000100000000000000, 0b00000000000000001000000000000000,
    0b00000000000000010000000000000000, 0b00000000000000100000000000000000,
    0b00000000000001000000000000000000, 0b00000000000010000000000000000000,
    0b00000000000100000000000000000000, 0b00000000001000000000000000000000,
    0b00000000010000000000000000000000, 0b00000000100000000000000000000000,
    0b00000001000000000000000000000000, 0b00000010000000000000000000000000,
    0b00000100000000000000000000000000, 0b00001000000000000000000000000000,
    0b00010000000000000000000000000000, 0b00100000000000000000000000000000,
    0b01000000000000000000000000000000, 0b10000000000000000000000000000000,
};

int main() {
  std::array<size_t, 32> rezults{};

  // clang-format off
  std::array<int, 5> input{
      0b00000000000000000001000000000001,
      0b01000000000000000010000000000000,
      0b00000000001000000010000000000000,
      0b00000000010000000001000000000000,
      0b01000000000000000011000000000001,
  };
  // clang-format on

  for (size_t val : input) {
    for (size_t index = 0; index < masks.size(); ++index) {
      rezults[index] += val & masks[index];
    }
  }

  unsigned int response = 0;
  for (size_t index = 0; index < masks.size(); ++index) {
    unsigned int mask = masks[index];
    unsigned int val = rezults[index] >> 1;

    response |= val == mask ? mask : 0;
  }

  std::cout << "0b" << std::bitset<32>(response) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А нужно ли так старательно избегать if-ов?

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин вы это у вопрошающего спросите) в любом случае совсем без if-ов не получилось

Comment: Блин, а я и не заметил. Придётся удалить свой ответ.